# Get id as a field in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a small database on firestore. 
When I made a POST request, I get a response with all the fields, plus some other including name field:

```
{
    "name": "projects/example-27d5e/databases/(default)/documents/cars/8inm4gXQwzVj5OrBbYoJ",
    "fields": {
        "Field3": {
            "stringValue": "3"
        },
        "Field1": {
            "stringValue": "1"
        },
        "Field2": {
            "stringValue": "2"
        }
    },
    "createTime": "2018-07-29T11:26:52.292609Z",
    "updateTime": "2018-07-29T11:26:52.292609Z"
}
```

Where **8inm4gXQwzVj5OrBbYoJ** is my document id.
Is there any way to store this id as a single field?

Answer (score 2):

There is no automated way to store the ID of a document as a field in that document.

In general I'd recommend against doing so, since it's needless duplication of data: whenever you read a document, Firestore returns its ID too. If you're struggling with how to get both the ID and the data while reading, show the code that you've tried, so we can have a look.

Comment: I just want to store my id as a regular field. So, for example, when I move to some other REST API, I can make a few changes to make everything work. I'm not really sure why they do that. Firebase always was a mistery to me :)

Comment: The reason for not storing the ID in the document is precisely that: another document might require to use another ID for the same document. But either way: if you want to store the ID in the document, you will need to do that in your own code. There is nothing built into the API for it.